# Remote fuse switch

Tags: electrical, fuse-panel, switches

I'm trying to find an on-off switch that connects into a standard 10-20A fuse block.  I want to feed the wires through the fuse panel to a remote switch so I can easily toggle power to the corresponding circuit.  (the switch, or its adaptor, would require its own in-line fuse of course.)

I can find "fuse taps" but I can't find anything that allows me to switch off the circuit through the fuse block.  What names would this component go under?

Comment: google "GTC CT6100 Fuse Socket Connector Kit"

Answer (score 2):

There are a few products that could be readily adapted to this.  Electronic Specialties makes a "Fuse Buddy Current Loop" and Painless Wiring makes a "Fuse Loop."  Both are designed to let you read circuit current using a clamp ammeter, but you could splice a toggle switch into the wire loop.